# Python pickle dump memory error

Tags: python, list, pickle

I have a very large list that I want to write to file. My list is 2 dimensional, and each element of the list is a 1 dimensional list. Different elements of the 2 dimensional list has 1 dimensional lists of varying size.

When my 2D list was small, pickle dump worked great. But now it just gives me memory error.

Any suggestions on how to store and reload such arrays to disk?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate. The solution was to change the pickling protocol to 2.

Comment: Ive tried that but it doesn't help for really big data

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep it simple and use something like pickle, the best thing is to use cPickle. This library is written in C and can handle bigger files and is faster than pickle.